# Intuition on O(number of leaves) for master theorem

Tags: time-complexity, master-theorem

I am trying to develop the intuition of the master theorem for the case where $a > b^{d}$ [Case 3] [in this video](https://youtu.be/zMYHz5s45T4?t=499). In the video, they say that since most of the work is done at the leaves, we should expect $O(\text{number of leaves})$ but I don't see how that is similar to  $O(n^{\log_b a}$), which one would get from the proof.

I just need the connection to the intuition as in how to see  $O(n^{\log_b a}$) from $O(\text{number of leaves})$ even in the least rigorous way.  I don't need the actual proof. The presenter gets on to the proof where $n$ is a power of $b$ later on, which is easier to follow but I would like to know so that I don't have to look up the material every time I need to check my work. Given the order of the presentation, I suspect that the intuition can be obtained without the proof for now but I could also be wrong and would appreciate being corrected if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence in question is $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$. Suppose that $n = b^k$, and the leaves are at $n = 1$. The root $b^k$ has $a$ children labelled $b^{k-1}$ (the label is the size of the subproblem). Each one of them has $a$ children labelled $b^{k-2}$, and in total there are $a^2$ children at depth $2$ labelled $b^{k-2}$. More generally, there are $a^\ell$ children at depth $\ell$ labelled $b^{k-\ell}$. In particular, taking $k = \ell$, we see that there are $a^k$ leaves. Since $n = b^k$, we get that the number of leaves is
$$
a^k = (b^{\log_b a})^k = (b^k)^{\log_b a} = n^{\log_b a}.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by labelled? Is it the size of the subproblem as that is what I can link to?

Comment: Right, it's the size of the subproblem.

Comment: How did you get from $a^k$ to $(b^{\log_b a})^k$ in the last line?

Comment: What is the definition of $\log_b a$?

Comment: The maximum number of levels

Comment: That's not the definition of $\log_b a$. Are you familiar with the definition of logarithm? If not, you can consult Wikipedia or many other sources.

Comment: It is impossible to understand a formula involving logarithms without first understanding logarithms.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were referring to what those mean based on a recursion tree. And I made a mistake reading n instead of a. The maximum number of levels is $\log_a n$ and not $\log_b a$

Comment: @heretoinfinity - The maximum number of levels is $\log_b n$.

Comment: The definition of $\log_b a$ is the exponent of $b$ that would give you $a$. Now I see it. Thanks.